# Slicing the output of multilabel predict_proba

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn MultiOutputClassifier and create a **multi-label** output for 7 distinct classes using:

```
multilabel_model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

which gives me an array with shape `(7, 14545, 2)` that contains both probabilities for the class being 0 and being 1:

```
[array([[9.7169727e-01, 2.8302711e-02],
        [9.9807453e-01, 1.9254771e-03],
        [9.9955606e-01, 4.4392250e-04],
        ...,
        [9.9957782e-01, 4.2216384e-04],
        [9.9833119e-01, 1.6688267e-03],
        [9.9959826e-01, 4.0173010e-04]], dtype=float32),
 array([[9.7968739e-01, 2.0312620e-02],
        [9.9961036e-01, 3.8966016e-04],
        [9.9990100e-01, 9.8974662e-05],
        ...,
```

Now I am looking for a way to slice the array such that the output only contains the probability for each of the 7 possible classes to equal 1 i.e. an output that would looks like this:

```
[[0.3,0.45,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.45,0.2],
[0.1,0.45,0.2,0.3,0.45,0.2,0.1],
...]
```

Is there a way of using some slicing magic to achieve this or does this require a sophisticated custom function?

Comment: Are you sure that you are talking about multi-label (a sample can belong to more that one classes simultaneously) and not simply multi-class (a sample can belong to one and only one class)? Please update your question (and title) to clarify.

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for asking! yes multi-label (a sample can belong to more than one classes simultaneously) it is, hence the use of the MultiOutputClassifier

Comment: MultiOutputClassifier works for multi-class, too. In any case, in multi-label the sum of the class probabilities for a single sample is not 1.0 (neither are your posted examples, despite that you say so in the text).

Comment: Ah I get your confusion, sorry I did not choose my words wisely :D with "classes to equal 1" I mean I only want the respective probability values for prediction "1" - not them being in sum equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just extract the probabilities for `1` (2nd position) use:

```py
probas = multilabel_model.predict_proba(X_test)
# probas.shape == (7, 14545, 2)

one_probas = probas[:, :, 1].reshape((probas.shape[1], probas.shape[0]))
# one_probas.shape == (14545, 7)
```